# Python XML Parsing regex

Tags: python, regex, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing

**Object: Match strings in file to string in XML. Replace
Match with comments**

**cat File.txt**

```
RHO_BID_RT
RHO_ASK_RT
```

**XML FILE CONTENTS**

```
<field name="RHO_BID_RT" type="float" id="0x01D3" sequence="1"/>
<field name="RHO_ASK_RT" type="float" id="0x01D4" sequence="1"/>
```

**INTENDED RESULTS in XML CONTENTS**

```
 <!-- Removed RHO_BID_RT-->
 <!-- Removed RHO_ASK_RT-->
```

**CODE**

```
import re

word_file = 'File.txt'
xml_file  = '../file.xml'

with open(word_file) as words:
    regex = r'<[^>]+ *field name="({})"[^>]+>'.format(
        '|'.join(word.rstrip() for word in words)
    )

with open(xml_file) as xml:
    for line in xml:
        line = re.sub(regex, r'<!!-- REMOVED \1 -->', line.rstrip())
        print(line)
```

Comment: did you mean '<!! REMOVED' or did you mean '<!-- REMOVED'? Also, what problem are you having with it?

Comment: Yes I did mean '<!-- REMOVED but do not think this is root issue for me

Answer (score 1):

Use an **XML parser**, like [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/).

The idea is to read a list of words and construct an xpath expression that would check the `name` attribute to be one of these words. Then, replace the elements by calling `replace()`:

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.etree import Comment


with open('words.txt') as f:
    words = [line.strip() for line in f]

xpath = '//field[{}]'.format(" or ".join(['@name = "%s"' % word for word in words]))

tree = etree.parse('input.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for element in tree.xpath(xpath):
    root.replace(element, Comment('REMOVED'))

print etree.tostring(tree)
```

For the following contents of `input.xml`:

```
<fields>
    <field name="RHO_BID_RT" type="float" id="0x01D3" sequence="1"/>
    <field name="RHO_ASK_RT" type="float" id="0x01D4" sequence="1"/>
</fields>
```

and `words.txt`:

```
RHO_BID_RT
RHO_ASK_RT
```

it prints:

```
<fields>
    <!--REMOVED-->
    <!--REMOVED-->
</fields>
```

---

Alternatively, construct a set of words and check the `name` attribute value in a loop:

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.etree import Comment


with open('words.txt') as f:
    words = set([line.strip() for line in f])

tree = etree.parse('input.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for element in tree.xpath('//field[@name]'):
    if element.attrib['name'] in words:
        root.replace(element, Comment('REMOVED'))

print etree.tostring(tree)
```

Comment: Appears I do not have this module.  I will see what can be done. thank you.